# What exception to throw when an important parameter/dependency is missing?

Tags: java, oop, exception

Take this method

```
/**
 * @return List of group IDs the person belongs to
 *
 */
public List<String> getGroups() {
    if (this.getId().equals("")) return null;
}
```

I would like to throw exception instead returning null, what's the exception to throw when an important parameter/dependency has not been set?

Comment: This code will raise an NPE if `getID()` returns null. It would be better to use `if ("".equals(this.getId())) ...`

Comment: I have that defined in an abstract class and there is a try catch inside, and will return empty string on failure.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I'd use [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) if the parameter/argument is controlled from outside, or [`IllegalStateException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) if the method is just called at a wrong moment (state). In your specific case I think it's the latter. A (dubious) alternative is [`NullPointerException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

This should however be explicitly documented in the `@throws` so that the user understands the reason.

Comment: The context of the question is indeed limited. As far as I can see, the ISE is the best choice. I also explicitly stated that, so I don't see how that is bad :)

Comment: Is there a magic how can I update the comment section in Eclipse to automatically regen missing @params and add @throws section? Maybe a shortcut?

Comment: Sorry, don't know that. It will be automatically added for non-runtime-exceptions (when you generate/update the `throws` clause), but not for runtime-exceptions.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can use 'Alt-Shift-J' when the cursor is at the beginning of your method declaration to generate the method javadoc comment.  That will generate a new javadoc block for you, though, it won't add on to what's there, so not sure it's all that helpful for existing documented methods.

Answer (score 6):

How about [IllegalStateException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)?

Answer (score 5):

I would use an IllegalStateException because the id is state of the owner. If the id would have passed as parameter, an IllegalArgumentException would be right.

Answer (score 3):

If its not possible to ensure that the id is always set (by requiring it in the constructor for example, where you could check that a valid id has been passed) then I think the other suggestions to throw [IllegalStateException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) are correct.  But it would be better to try and ensure that your object can't get into this state in the first place if at all possible

Answer (score 3):

Instead of throwing an exception, you should just return an empty list. If a dependency/parameter isn't met, then there are no results. From the comments and code posted, it looks like that's the expected behavior.  If the id is empty, then there are no groups attached, thus an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own Exception type by extending Exception.  That way calling functions can catch that particular Exception and handle it gracefully as appropriate.
Note, you can do the same thing with just about anything that Extends Exception, but I prefer to create my own Exception classes so I can be very robust in my exception handling.  This is, of course, up to you though.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? IllegalArgumentException is made exactly for an illegal argument.

Comment: It depends on how many different types of illegal arguments you want to trap for.  I like extending Excpetion, or in this case IllegalArgumentException just to have a specific Exception class to deal with different types of conditions I want to deal with.  It makes Exception processing easier and more robust, IMHO.

-Jay